# Why type error is appearing?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm learning JavaScript and was playing with functions when encountered error when running this code:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [{
  prop1: "a",
  prop2: "b"
}, {
  prop1: "c",
  prop2: "d"
}];

function testFunc(arrayOfObjects) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
    arrayOfObjects[i].newFunctionProp = function() {
      console.log("Hello!");
    };
  }
}

arrayOfObjects[0].newFunctionProp();
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: arrayOfObjects[0].newFunctionProp is not a function
```

Can anybody explain why this property is not a function when I assigned a function expression to that property in for loop before?

Comment: The reason is you didn't call `testFunc`...

Comment: @DenysSéguret Thanks, it helps. I'm such an inattentive person...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Denys Séguret](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263525/denys-s%C3%A9guret) mentioned, one need to run testFunc `testFunc(arrayOfObjects);` so it creates property needed.